# Assignment to print function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variable-assignment

A friend of mine is doing a Python tutorial course and asked for some help because her code wasn't working as expected.

I was able to identify the issue immediately and help her deduce the issue for herself. The code was along these lines.

```
myValue = 575.0
print=(myValue)
```

Obviously, **print** failed. But when I say that it failed, I only mean that it failed to print anything. The interpreter still executed that line without any issues. So, my question is, why isn't the assignment operator raising a syntax error?

Comment: Why should it raise a syntax error? It just assigns a value to the local variable `print`, thereby shadowing the builtin function of that name in the same scope. While this is a very bad idea, it's not forbidden by any syntactic rule.

Comment: Welcome to the world of dynamic languages. `print` is just a variable that can have any object bound to it. It starts out as the python print function but you can change it to anything you want.

Comment: Great. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't raise an error because in Python 3, `print` is a regular function. And function objects are bound to names, so `print` is a name (a "variable") that refers to a particular function object.

Since functions are no different than variables, you can reassign them however you please:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

add = "ha-ha, I'm a string"
```

The parentheses after the `=` sign are the kind of parentheses you use in math:

```
print = (1 + 2)  # print == 3
```

Parentheses immediately after a name represent a function call.

But now `print` is broken, and you'll never ever be able to print anything! Not really - there's a copy in `__builtins__.print`:

```
print = __builtins__.print
```

However, you can mess that up just as easily:

```
__builtins__.print = 5
```

---

In Python 2, however, `print` is a statement, *not* a regular function, so this fails:

```
Python 2.7.16 (default, Dec  3 2019, 07:02:07)
>>> print = 5
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print = 5
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I didn't realise that Python variables could be function pointers as well. Your code cautions are useful too. Do you have any insight into the reasons for the change in status between Python 2 and 3? The Python 2 version seems safer to me.

Comment: @buzzdriving, see [PEP 3105](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/)

Comment: Will do. Thanks!

Comment: Python's variables "aren't" their contents, and they certainly aren't "function pointers". Python's variables are **names for** things, and functions are objects ('things"), therefore they can be named (and renamed).

Answer (score 0):

Experiment by doing this:

```
my_value = 575.0
print = (my_value)
print(print)
```

Notice you get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jchca/PycharmProjects/Josepe_project/Josepe/Practice10.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(print)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

In essence, she overwrote the print function so `print` now acts as the float value (this is in Python 3.x)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Joshua.